# What is the cost for machine to compare two integers?

Tags: assembly, integer, comparison

I've found out some information about comparing integers for a machine such as an Intel x86, but I don't know more and I wanted to have some precision on the subject.

I thought that on x86 machine, it compares first the Big-End byte, and then the Little-End byte. Is this correct?

How much cycles does that need? I thought it was around 6 cycles, but I can't find anything to concur on what I think is true.

Comment: Please specify machine type (especially word) and integer size.

Comment: Presumably, addressing mode matters too.

Answer (score 2):

x86 by itself is just an architecture. If you are into cycle counts, you have to name the exact model or at least family. Generally however chips have native width hardware units (that is 32 or 64 bit) as such they don't do it byte-by-byte. Also, nowadays chips are superscalar meaning they can execute instructions in parallel and out-of-order meaning they can reorder instructions as long as outcome is the same and they have prefetching, caches and other factors that may greatly influence performance. Finally, a compare by itself isn't terribly useful, it's usually accompanied by something that used the flags set (such as a conditional jump).

The intel optimization manual has latency tables, and also you can find [some on the internet](http://www.agner.org/optimize/). Since `CMP` is a `SUB` in disguise, usually 2 or 3 can be executed per clock under ideal conditions.